# Count records from different columns (MySQL/php)

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table like this

```
     id  |  block1  |  block2  |  block3
-----------------------------------------------
     1   |  John    |  John    |
     2   |  Mark    |          |
     3   |          |  Frank   |  Frank
```

how i count how many john, Mark and Frank are in the table? es.

```
John - 2
Mark - 1
Frank - 2
```

i use the query below but is only for one column and i don't know how have the same result for all the columns. I think is a helpful query becouse i read is possible have the results maybe for the last month or year

```
SELECT block1,
COUNT(*) AS total
FROM table
GROUP BY block1
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

thank you
(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to unpivot the table, then apply grouping:

```
SELECT block, COUNT(*) AS 'total'
FROM (
   SELECT block1 AS block
   FROM mytable    

   UNION ALL

   SELECT block2
   FROM mytable       

   UNION ALL

   SELECT block3
   FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY block
```

Comment: thank you very much! help me you helpo me a lot. Work perfectly for me

Comment: @gege Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select columns separately and use `UNION` to merge them. Then `COUNT` them. You can try this -

```
SELECT col_block, COUNT(col_block) FROM (
(SELECT block1 col_block,
FROM table)
UNION ALL
(SELECT block2 col_block,
FROM table)
UNION ALL
(SELECT block3 col_block,
FROM table)) tbl
GROUP BY col_block
```

Comment: thanks anyway, i use the query post from Georgos Betsos

Comment: @gege Both are same. :)